# Is there a way to allocates sorted values in a dataframe to groups based on alternating elements

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas DataFrame like:

```
COURSE  BIB#  COURSE 1  COURSE 2  STRAIGHT-GLIDING     MEAN  PRESTASJON
1          2    20.220    22.535             19.91  21.3775    1.073707
0          1    21.235    23.345             20.69  22.2900    1.077332
```

This is from a pilot and the DataFrame may be much longer when we perform the real experiment. Now that I have calculated the performance for each BIB#, I want to allocate them into two different groups based on their performance. I have therefore written the following code:

```
df1 = df1.sort_values(by='PRESTASJON', ascending=True)
```

This sorts values in the DataFrame. Now I want to assign even rows to one group and odd rows to another. How can I do this?

I have no idea what I am looking for. I have looked up in the documentation for the random module in Python but that is not exactly what I am looking for. I have seen some questions/posts pointing to a scikit-learn stratification function but I don't know if that is a good choice. Alternatively, is there a way to create a loop that accomplishes this? I appreciate your help.

Here a figure to illustrate what I want to accomplish

[image: What I want to accomplish]

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you are looking for, but `pd.cut()` might help out. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html

Comment: Yes. I am sorry. I have tried my best. I will check it out

Comment: Does the figure help?

Comment: Are you trying to just take every other element?

Comment: Yes @MadPhysicist :)

Comment: @ChristianMagelssen. I've edited your question to state that clearly. Let me know if the edit is acceptable (you can always revert it if not). I will leave it up to you to delete the paragraph about "I have no idea what I am looking for".

Comment: @MadPhysicist Cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you splitting the dataframe alternatingly? If so, you can do:

```
df1 = df1.sort_values(by='PRESTASJON', ascending=True)

for i,d in df1.groupby(np.arange(len(df1)) %2):
    print(f'group {i}')
    print(d)
```

Another way without `groupby`:

```
df1 = df1.sort_values(by='PRESTASJON', ascending=True)
mask = np.arange(len(df1)) %2

group1 = df1.loc[mask==0]

group2 = df1.loc[mask==1]
```

Comment: I tried it and it works on with my current data. Will np.arrange() ensure that I get two groups that are of app. equal performance?

Comment: Yes, you would have all the even rows in one group and the odd in the other.

Comment: @ChristianMagelssen arange is just a counter from zero to the number of rows

Comment: I see. It took me some time to understand what it did, especially with the %2

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
threshold = 0.5
df1['group'] = df1['PRESTASJON'] > threshold
```

Or if you want values for your groups:

```
df['group'] = np.where(df['PRESTASJON'] > threshold, 'A', 'B')
```

Here, `'A'` will be assigned to column `'group'` if precision meets our threshold, otherwise `'B'`.

---

**UPDATE**: Per OP's update on the post, if you want to group them alternatively into two groups:

```
#sort your dataframe based on precision column
df1 = df1.sort_values(by='PRESTASJON')
#create new column with default value 'A' and assign even rows (alternative rows) to 'B'
df1['group'] = 'A'
df1.iloc[1::2,-1] = 'B'
```

Comment: Hey @Ehsan. Thank you. The only thing is that  I don't know the threshold. I just have a column of sorted values. I have tried to add a figure

Comment: @ChristianMagelssen How would you want to define your groups A and B then? do you want to just cut them into two equal sized groups or statistically find a threshold?

Comment: @ChristianMagelssen I see your edit on the post now. I will add an update that group them alternatively. Please let us now if that is what you were looking for. If not, please elaborate so we can understand better. Thank you

Comment: Two equal sized groups

Comment: I appreciate your help

Comment: @ChristianMagelssen Please see if the update helps. Thank you.